# Cygwin - grep ( if file contains )

Tags: awk, grep, gawk

Okay so basically I have a list of emails in

```
EMAILS.TXT
```

Then I have another bunch .txt files containing, email:phonenumber:name

```
Compiled1.txt
Compiled2.txt
Compiled3.txt
...
```

Can I use grep or gawk, to search a folder containg compiled1, compiled2 to see if lines contain emails from the .txt file?

So example

```
email.txt Contains " example@example.com " & " example1@example1.com "
```

Folder containing

```
Compiled1.txt & Compiled2.txt have both these lines
```

Cygwin/Gnuwin outputs lines from compiled1 & compiled2 IF it contains those specified from emails.txt

```
Output > example@example.com:000000:ExampleUser 
         example1@example1.com:00010101:ExampleUser2
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
grep -Fi -f EMAILS.TXT Compiled*.txt
```

`-f EMAILS.TXT` uses the lines of `EMAILS.TXT` as search patterns.
`-F` disables special treatment of symbols like `.` or `?`.
`-i` case insensitive search.

Output will be of the form

```
File-in-which-a-match-was-found:Matched-line-from-that-file
```

In case of your example:

```
Compiled1.txt:example@example.com:000000:ExampleUser
Compiled1.txt:example1@example1.com:00010101:ExampleUser2
Compiled2.txt:example@example.com:000000:ExampleUser
Compiled2.txt:example1@example1.com:00010101:ExampleUser2
```

If your are also interested in the line numbers, add `-n` to the command.